# Remove icon from bookmark in firefox toolbar in userChrome.css

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, css, xul

I am trying to remove the icon of one specific bookmark in the bookmarks toolbar of Firefox (20.0). That is, the dotted box just to the left of "Read Later" in the following image:

[image]

I have my `userChrome.css` file as follows:

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"); /*only needed once*/
.bookmark-item[label="Read Later"]{display: none;}
```

Also, the following does not work either:

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"); /*only needed once*/
#personal-bookmarks toolbarbutton[label="Read Later"] image{
    display: none !important;
    -moz-margin-end: 0px !important;
}
```

Unfortunately, this does nothing. Any ideas?

---

Links I have used:

[#bookmarksBarContent toolbarbutton modifications in userChrome.css](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/760156)

[How to remove icons from FF 4 Bookmarks Toolbar?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/792988)

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the bookmark's icon. Try the following:

```
@namespace url(http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul);

.bookmark-item .toolbarbutton-icon[label="Read Later"] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Alternatively, you can target **all** blank bookmark icons (that are not in folders) with the following:

```
@namespace url(http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul);

.bookmark-item .toolbarbutton-icon:not([type="menu"]):not([src]) {
    display: none !important;
}
```